# Include multiple separate for loops in jinja

Tags: python, for-loop, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to pass multiple dictionaries to the jinja in a single html file and use multiple for loops to populate the data. Can't seem to get it working, I've tried searching all over. I only find info about nested for loop etc... Is it even possible? Or should I look towards javascript or programmatically handle in python? Any help is appreciated!

```
{% block main %}
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Book Title</th>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>ISBN</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- Iterate through each item in the dict and output the ISBN, book name, author name, and year -->
        {% for book_result in book_result %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ book_result['bookname'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ book_result['author'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ book_result['year'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ book_result['isbn'] }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
        <tr>
            {% for read in read %}
                <td>{{ read['val'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ read['val2'] }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
</table>
    <div>
    {% for review_result in review_result %}
        <div>
            <p class="text-left row">{{ review_result['review'] }}</p>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Comment: At least you have suspicious looking for-loops here. Instead of `{%  for book_result in book_result %}` I'd use `{% for book in book_result %}`. It looks bad idea to use same name as your iteration value as your list has. What variables you give to your Jinja template. Give us examples.

Comment: @ex4 this is the python code: ```return render_template("book.html", book_result=book_result, review_result=review_result, read=read)```

Answer (score -1):

```
book_result = [
    {
        'bookname': 'Some book',
        'author': 'Some author',
        'year': 'Some year',
        'isbn': 'Some isbn',
        'reviews': [
            {
                'user': 'john',
                'body': 'Great book!',
            },
            {
                'user': 'lucy',
                'body': 'Hey I really liked your book!',
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        'bookname': 'Some other book',
        'author': 'Some other author',
        'year': 'Some other year',
        'isbn': 'Some other isbn',
        'reviews': [
            {
                'user': 'jim',
                'body': 'Awesome book!',
            },
        ],
    },
]

{% for book in book_result %}
  {{ book.bookname }} - {{ book.author }}
  <br>
  {% for review in book.reviews %}
    {{ review.body }} - {{ review.user }}
  {% endfor %}
  <br><br>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thank you, this puts in info from only one dictionary, right? I have three, books, reviews, and some other values, so while it works for the books,  I have multiple reviews for the same book that I'm trying to loop as well which wouldn't work. Is that correct?

Comment: What you want is a `list` containing dictionaries.

Comment: that's what I initially had, but the list of dicts have the same book data and only reviews were different, so each time the loop runs I get book details which ends up displaying the duplicate book details for each review!

Comment: That sounds you want nested loops after all.

Comment: Updated with nested lists.

Comment: thank you @onosendi, I'll try with this now and update you all! appreciate taking your time to help me!

Comment: I went back and modified it to accept book details as vars because I'll only ever pass details of just one book. so now I have just one loop for all the reviews.